# Big-O Analysis Homework: Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am new to a data structure class and had only touched the subject of Big-O slightly in my previous CS courses. I am still learning about it online, but I just wanted to make sure that I am doing this right. There are some homework questions regarding Big-O analysis and I just wanted to double-check with you guys.

Here are some of the questions that got me confused, and the analysis I made:

```
//Part (a)
int x = 0;
for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--)             //N times
  if((i % 3) == 0) break;               //Executed O(N) times
    else x += n;                        //Executed O(N) times
Analysis: O(n)

//Part (b)
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)              //N times
  for(int j = 0; j < (n * n /3); j++)   //N^2 times
     x += j;                            //Executed O(N^3) times
Analysis: O(N^3)

//Part (c)
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)             //N times
  for(int j = 0; j < (i * i); j++)      //N^2 times
     x += j;                            //Executed O(N^3) times
Analysis: O(N^3)
```

I am sorry if my analysis is wrong or all over the place, I'm still really new to this concept! Any input and/or explanations would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: part (a) looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part a: The loop will execute at most three times. Three is a constant upper limit, so the complexity is constant (aka `O(1)`).

Part b: You are correct about this one.

Part c: Execute this loop in your head and think about how many times `x += j` run depending on the value of `i`. If `i` is zero, then the inner loop will run 0 times, if `i` is one, the inner loop will run 1 time -- in general, the inner loop will run `i^2` (i squared) times. The total number of times that the `x += j` line will run, when we count the entire thing (outer loop included), will be:

> 0<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + (n - 1)<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>

This mathematical expression is equal to `(1/6)n(n + 1)(2n + 1)` ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28i%5E2%29%2C+i+%3D+0..n)), and `O((1/6)n(n + 1)(2n + 1))` is equal to `O(n^3)`. So you got the right answer, but the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. All pretty clear. Can you explain why b) is O(n^3)? I thought that n/3 * n gives us n so => n * n = n^2. And you say that it is n/3 * n = (n^2)/3 => n * n(^2)/3 = (n^3)/3. But n/3 is three times less. Shouldn' we take it as a constant?

Comment: @user1551066 In part b, the outer loop runs `n` times, and the inner loop runs `n * n / 3` times. So, we multiply these together to get `O(n * n * n / 3)`, which is equal to `O((1/3) * n^3)`. Since we can multiply or divide the expression inside the `O(...)` by any number and get something that is equal (similar to how you can multiply or divide both the numerator and denominator of a fraction to get an equivalent fraction), we multiply it by 3, which cancels out the `1/3` and leaves us with `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! For part (a), isn't the for loop executed linearly, since it decrements every time it goes to the else statement and returns back to the for statement? I understand why the if statement is executed O(1) time, but I'm not sure about the for and else statements...

Comment: @Riadiani Pick some arbitrary value of `n` (say, 50) and execute part a in your head. (Or you could do it on a computer -- just print something every time the loop executes). You will quickly see why the loop will only execute three times at the most, regardless of what `n` is. Whenever you can say "this statement will never execute more than X times," where X is a constant, then the algorithm is `O(1)` time.

Comment: @Adrian thank you! I get it now! Silly me, I kept forgetting the break statement when I tried running this in my head with big values of n!